# Angular 2 restrict input with 1 digits after comma

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I have a problem with my custom directive written in Angular 2. I want to prevent entering more than 1 digits after comma. When I enter digits that is all right, but when I put my number with comma and 1 digits after it I can't put any key in part before comma.

```
export class InputTemplateDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    @Input('inputTemplate') highlightColor: number;

    @HostListener('keypress',['$event']) _onKeyPress(e){
        let pattern = /^-?\d*\,?\d*$/;
        if (e.key==="." || this.el.nativeElement.value.length>=14 || pattern.exec(this.el.nativeElement.value)===null) 
            e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: `^[+-]?\d+(,\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: The text `I want to prevent enter more then 1 digit after comma.` enters in conflict with the title. So, one or two digits after comma?

Comment: sorry, 1 digit ) But trouble isn't in quantity of digits after comma i think )